# Why would plugging in a logic probe change values in a digital circuit?

Tags: power-supply, debugging, protoboard

I teach a digital logic course, in which the students used TTL chips and LEDs on digital trainers (including the [Global Specialties PB-503C](http://www.globalspecialties.com/electronic-trainers/analog-a-digital-circuit-design-workstation/item/98-pb-503c.html)).  With one student's PB-503C, the values on the lights (both discrete LEDs and the ones built into the kit) change their values when I connect the appropriate wires of a logic probe to its power and ground (without touching the tip to anything).  This happens with multiple logic probes (and a voltmeter, iirc) but not on other students' kits.  Why might this happen?

FWIW, the power supply on the PB-503C seems wonky.  I measured the 5V rail with a voltmeter and got over 6V.  I had the student use an adjustable rail instead.

Updates:

- It is a hand-held digital multimeter, not a voltmeter.  I can try an analog one in the future.
- The logic probe is not externally powered.  It draws power from the kit.
- I could probably get hold of an oscilloscope but am not sure how much I could do with it, since my knowledge is limited to digital electronics.
- The power supply is not under much load, just a few dozen TTL chips.
- The change to the LEDs is that some that are off go on, and vice versa.  The LEDs have integrated resistors and are connected to the outputs of a pair of LS163 synchronous counters.  The changes to the lights are not regular, as they would be if the clock input were changing.  (The clock is a pushbutton.)
- I used a knob-adjustable rail to get 5V (at zero load), but that tended to drift off too and need readjusting.

Comment: Which logic probe are you using exactly? Does the probe have external power supply or is it powered from the kit? What exactly happens when you connect the voltmeter? To what do you connect the voltmeter? Is it a hand held unit or a bench meter? Do you have an oscilloscope to check what's actually happening to the power supply output? What about the other rails? How exactly do lights change?

Comment: re:PSU wonky. Was it under any load at the time? A lot of SMPSes will drift upwards with zero load - it may take as little as 10ma load (470R) to keep them tamed.

Comment: A voltmeter (not a multimeter?) is causing the LED to light?

Comment: Also is the voltmeter analogue or digital?

Comment: Thanks for all of the questions.  I've tried answering them in the updates.

Comment: With such limited knowedge of electronics, what are you doing teaching a course in it!!?

Comment: I'm knowledgeable about digital electronics (MIT EECS SB, SM, PhD), which is what I'm teaching, not analog electronics.

Comment: There is no such thing as just digital electronics, as you are discovering.  I suppose if you stick to purely digital chips and never exceed 10 MHz you can get away with that, but anything past that has a analog component.  More and more "digital" manipulation is done in processors, with circuits having significant analog components.

Comment: It's really an intro computer architecture course, not digital electronics.  The students build a 3-instruction computer out of counters, ALUs, registers, tri-state buffers, multiplexers, and basic logic gates, with the program stored on a PROM.  They hand-clock it, and no student has yet reached 10 MHz. :-)

Comment: I should have said above that I'm knowledge about "digital logic", not "digital electronics".

Answer (score 4):

Put a scope on the power supply.  It is probably oscillating.  This could be due to a faulty component, a bad solder joint (output cap not properly connected, for example), or a marginal design that happens to work in the other units.  Put a 1 µF ceramic cap accross the power supply and see if you get the same effect.  If so, put such a cap directly accross the power supply output as close to the regulator chip as you can.

When you say the power supply is "wonky", is it just that unit or all these units.  If all of them, then it sounds like a bad design.  If just this unit, then it is even more evidence that something is wrong around the power supply of that unit.  Inspect the parts and solder joints of the power supply of the wonky unit carefully.

Comment: Especially if this is old and primitive enough to have a linear supply, it could be a dead filter cap, with those in the logic probe partially making up the lack when it is connected.

Comment: I'll give it a try.  I haven't checked the power supplies of the properly functioning units but will check them out too.

Answer (score 2):

Since you changed the behavior just by plugging the probe into power, without touching any of the logic signals, that sounds like a power supply problem, not a logic problem. Probably the load current or capacitance of the probe changed the supply behavior, which it shouldn't do unless there's a fault in the supply.

One exception is what Brian pointed out, "A lot of SMPSes will drift upwards with zero load". A quick way to check if this is going on is to try the supply from a different kit (I assume you have several for your class) and see if has similar behavior. If you see this is expected behavior for this supply, a 100 - 1 kOhm resistor between Vcc and ground should   fix it. (I see from your link the supply is capable of 1 A, so 5 mA should not affect it except to fix this problem)

Otherwise, if the power supply is not working correctly, as your other tests show, it doesn't make much sense to do much more with that circuit. Repair or replace the power supply before you try to debug anything attached to it.

Comment: Thanks.  The kits are under warranty, and I'm not much of an analog hardware hacker, so I won't try switching or fixing the power supply myself.  I'll let y'all know what happens when I put in a resistor.

Comment: Make sure the behavior is consistent on all units before using the resistor as a solution. If this is the solution, that power supply is incredibly poorly chosen for this application --- when making a breadboard kit, they should have realized that very light loads would be a normal situation.